# How to end a conditional early in Python 3?

Tags: python

I wanted to know if there was any way to end a conditional early. For example, when I run the code and enter all values in between 0-100 the program does what it's supposed to. However, let's say I put a negative number as input #3. The program keeps on going until the very end, then I get "Invalid input. Enter a number between 0-100". I'm wondering if there is any way I can get that message as soon as I enter a number that's not in between 0-100. I'm a complete beginner, so I really don't know what I'm doing.

```
def e5():
    stdnt1 = float(input("Enter the first grade: "))
    stdnt2 = float(input("Enter the second grade: "))
    stdnt3 = float(input("Enter the third grade: "))
    stdnt4 = float(input("Enter the fourth grade: "))
    stdnt5 = float(input("Enter the fifth grade: "))
    if(0 <= (stdnt1 and stdnt2 and stdnt3 and stdnt4 and stdnt5) <= 100):
        avrg = (stdnt1 + stdnt2 + stdnt3 + stdnt4 + stdnt5) / 5
        print("The groups average is", avrg)
        grades = [stdnt1, stdnt2, stdnt3, stdnt4, stdnt5]
        grades.sort()
        print("The lowest grade is", grades[0])
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Enter number between 0-100")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend writing a function that takes the input and processes it.

```
def get_input(prompt):
    response = float(input(prompt))
    if 0 <= response <= 100:
        return response
    raise ValueError("Invalid input - enter number between 0-100")
```

This also has the advantage of simplying the first 5 lines of your function.

```
def e5():
    stdnt1 = get_input("Enter the first grade")
    # ...
```

You could also change the function to continue to ask the user using a while loop for valid input.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Perform some preliminary checks *as soon as* you get the input.  Example:

```
stdnt3 = float(input("Enter the third grade: "))
if not (0 <= stdnt3 and stdnt3 <= 100):
    raise SystemExit("Error: value is not between 0 and 100.")

stdnt4 = float(input("En...
```

### Edit

Note that your if-condition doesn't work as you expect.  This:

```
if(0 <= (stdnt1 and stdnt2 and stdnt3 and stdnt4 and stdnt5) <= 100):
```

Will be (logically) turned into:

```
# Step 1
booleanValue = stdnt1 and stdnt2 and stdnt3 and stdn4 and stdnt5  # a True or False

# Step 2
if 0 <= (booleanValue) <= 100

# Step 3
if (0 <= booleanValue) <= 100

# Step 4
if TrueOrFalse <= 100
```

TrueOrFalse will be `True` (casting usually to the number 1) or `False` (casting usually to the number 0).  That means that the if-condition will always evaluate to True and your `else` will never get called.  Instead, check each value individually, either with multiple if statements, or in a single if statement:

```
if (0 <= stdnt1 and stndt1 <= 100) and (0 <= stndt2 and stndt2 <= 100) and ...
```

Comment: How do I make it print "Error: value is not between 0 and 100"?

Comment: @EdgarR Try the `raise SystemExit` .  It will do just that.

Comment: Technically - `and` does not return a boolean value. It returns the first falsey value or the last value if they are all truthy. So this will technically compare the first 0 or the last value. Not desired behaviour in any case....

Answer (score 0):

Divide up your problems. You're trying to achieve two separate things here:

1. Validate your inputs
2. Calculate an average

Write separate functions for each of these... well.. functions!

```
def validate_grade(grade):
    if grade < 0 or grade > 100:
        raise InvalidGrade()  # This is a custom exception, I'll explain momentarily
    return grade
```

So this function will check if a given number is between 0 and 100 inclusive, if not it will raise an exception. In this case it's a custom exception, so that we can catch it only if this particular case occurs. In all other circumstances, normal Python exceptions will be raised.

Let's define that exception.

```
class InvalidGrade(Exception):
    pass
```

It really is just a standard exception with a different name! Easy but very helpful, here's how:

```
try:
    stdnt1 = validate_grade(float(input("Enter the first grade: ")))
    stdnt2 = validate_grade(float(input("Enter the second grade: ")))
    stdnt3 = validate_grade(float(input("Enter the third grade: ")))
    stdnt4 = validate_grade(float(input("Enter the fourth grade: ")))
    stdnt5 = validate_grade(float(input("Enter the fifth grade: ")))
except InvalidGrade:
    print("Invalid input. Enter number between 0-100")
else:
    calculate_grades(stdnt1, stdnt2, stdnt3, stdnt4, stdnt5)
```

Great! Now it will gather input, raise an exception if any one of those inputs is invalid, otherwise it will execute the yet-to-be-defined `calculate_grades` function. But before we do that, we have some very repetitive code to clean up.

Lets ask ourselves what we're really repeating with these 5 grades. The only difference between each line is "first", "second", "third", etc.

Aha! We could create a list of grade names, and then python can loop over that list to build a list of grade values.

```
grade_names = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"]
try:
    grade_values = [validate_grade(float(input("Enter the %s grade: " % name)))
                    for name in grade_names]
except InvalidGrade:
    print("Invalid input. Enter number between 0-100")
else:
    calculate_grades(*grade_values)
```

First we simply define a list of grade names by creating a list of strings.
Then inside the try block we use something called a [list comprehension](https://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php). It is simply a statement that gets evaluated for each item in a list, in this case that statement is the function `validate_grade` which happens to take the results of input then float as its parameters, and returns a value which is what will be saved in our grade values list.

Then, instead of passing each item one by one to `calculate_grades`, the `*` tells python to expand the list's elements as parameters for the function. Now if you were to say, add or remove a grade, you only have to change your code in one place.

Now for the final piece, lets define `calculate_grades`

```
def calculate_grades(*args):
    avrg = sum(args) / len(args)
    print("The groups average is", avrg)
    print("The lowest grade is", min(args))
```

The whole solution together

```
GRADE_NAMES = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"]


class InvalidGrade(Exception):
    pass


def validate_grade(grade):
    if grade < 0 or grade > 100:
        raise InvalidGrade()
    return grade


def calculate_grades(*args):
    print("The groups average is", sum(args) / len(args))
    print("The lowest grade is", min(args))


try:
    grade_values = [validate_grade(float(input("Enter the %s grade: " % name)))
                    for name in GRADE_NAMES]
except InvalidGrade:
    print("Invalid input. Enter number between 0-100")
else:
    calculate_grades(*grade_values)
```